# Joomla, is this a bad thing, injecting view, model and controller to container?

Tags: php, joomla, dependencies, containers

As the title says, I just want to ask if this is a bad thing or not if I inject all views, models, controllers and other classes like helpers into the container (IoC) for example like the following image.

Sample:

[image: Sample]

Note: In this case, I make my own base view, model and controller for my component so I don't use default Joomla instance like `JModelLegacy::getInstance();` or `JControllerLegacy::getInstance();`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. I've tired of constant changes that breaks extensions and force to rewrite them without any actual benefit.

I have forced all MVC classes of Joomla and added my prefix to them. Everything works just fine.

I do not think you will have a problem to load everything at once. At least with the list you've shown. If you would have extension with hundreds of views and models, may be you could be hurt.

On the other hand why would you do that? Decouple your library off Joomla's and it will load everything automatically.

Comment: (If you would have extension with hundreds of views and models, may be you could be hurt). Yeah I know, this is the first reason why I ask about it here, in the image above, that's just for example and maybe total of views, models and controllers more than 50+. (On the other hand why would you do that? Decouple your library off Joomla's and it will load everything automatically). No, they're not loaded automatically, they only loaded if I need one, I just feel like it and this is save my work since I can access anything from the container which is injected to all views, models and controllers.

Comment: One more reason is I want to create something like laravel inside Joomla also I only bind string or namespace/class name into the container and most of them is not object except the Joomla core. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I get you. Either way it is up to you how you struct your extension but direct answer to your question I would not worry to load everything at once.